# How to modify frames from camera in real time before showing the preview to the user in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, image-processing, video-processing, image-segmentation

I am building a video recording app with CameraX API in android studio.

I want to do two things:

a. Edit the frames received from the camera in realtime before showing them to the user(in this case I want to overlay another image on top of the received frame)

b. An option to record it as a video

I am using the ML Kit Selfie Segmentation API to cut out the person received from the camera feed.

And I want to paste that cut out person on top of another image (could be a another video frame or still image)

I can record video and use selfie segmentation separately but I haven't found a way to combine these two.

The problem I am facing is, I am not sure what type of `view` I should be using to show the edited frames in realtime at 15-30fps or more.

Also I don't know how to combine all these frames to record a video in realtime with audio from the mic.

Can anyone give me a nudge where should I be looking for?